# How to execute a shell script if file matches a regex using monit

Tags: shell, monit

I have this code in a monitrc file:

```
check file random.log with path /app/monit-5.27.1/conf/random.log
        ignore content = ".*favicon.*"
        if content = /app/monit-5.27.1/conf/test1.regex
         then exec "/usr/bin/bash -c '/app/monit-5.27.1/conf/count_logs.sh'"
```

test1.regex contains a regex expression and here is count_logs.sh file :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello, this is shell script running!!!"
count=$(pgrep -c 500, 502, 503)
if [[$count -ge 60]]; then
    exit 1
else:
    exit 0
fi
```

Basically, I want to count number of times random.log file has 500,502,503 present if a certain regex is satisfied and if count is greater than 60, restart the server.

regex is matching but the shell script is not running as per the log file.
How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you interesting in counting the number of processes for 500,502,503 with "pgrep".

The script snipped does not read any data from random.log, therefore nothing will be counted if you use "grep". The environment variable "MONIT_DESCRIPTION" contain some of the matching lines only.